Displaying Images from PostgreSQL Database in EJS Template using Node.js
I'm encountering an issue while trying to display images fetched from a PostgreSQL database in an EJS template using Node.js. The images are stored in a column named "fotograf" in the "corap" table, and they are in byte format. However, when I attempt to render these images in my EJS template, they do not appear on the screen, and I'm not receiving any errors.
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require("path")
const tasarim = path.join(__dirname,'../tasarim')


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('uygulama başarılı bir şekilde açılıyor ');
});
app.use('/tasarim', express.static('tasarim'));


 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
 app.use(express.json())
 app.set("view engine","ejs")
 app.set("views",tasarim)

 app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended:false
 }))



 const { Client } = require('pg');
 const client = new Client({
  user: '',
  host: '',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: 5432, 
 });

client.connect()
.then(() => console.log('PostgreSQL veritabanına bağlandı'))
.catch(err => console.error('Bağlantı hatası', err));


app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM corap');
    const coraplar = result.rows; 

    
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'tasarim', 'urunler.ejs'), { 
      coraplar
    });
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Veri alınamadı:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Veri alınamadı');
  }
});

urunler.ejs file
 <ul>
    <% coraplar.forEach(function(corap) { %>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
        
          <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%= corap.fotograf.toString() %>" alt="<%=  %>">

          <h3><%= corap.urun_adi %></h3>
          <p><%= corap.aciklama %></p>
          <span class="fiyat"><%= corap.fiyat %> TL</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    <% }); %>


  </ul>


Is corap.fotograf.toString() already base64 encoded? If not, try Buffer.from(corap.fotograf).toString('base64')

console.log(coraplar[0].fotograf); = 24649
